# Tasmota Websocket

Tags: websocket, tasmota

Is there a way to establish a websocket connection to tasmota devices?
or is there another way to permanently request data besides sending http requests all the time?

I would like to display the data on my website and would like to have real time data

I had already googled maybe someone knows of you a possibility.